# How to load an image from intent in Flutter?

Tags: android, android-intent, dart, flutter

I am sharing an image from the android photos app using the share button. The intent handle function looks something like this:

```
void handleFileIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("inside intent");
    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    fileName = imageUri.getPath();
```

The Uri turned into a string returns the following:

> content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F33/REQUIRE_ORIGINAL/NONE/257321333

The getPath() call on the Uri returns the following:

> /-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/33/REQUIRE_ORIGINAL/NONE/796304333

I am struggling to find a way to open these resources in Flutter. How do I do this?

I understand that these content URLs come bundled with the permissions required to open/access the images in Android. I understand that this context is not being necessarily being passed onto Flutter. I also understand that these are two different issues but they are related into loading the image into Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the resource permissions are bundled with the Intent. However, this should be transparent to you as you should be able to obtain an InputStream using (in MainActivity):

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
```

As the permission is only valid for the lifetime of the Intent, you should probably use this InputStream to immediately read the file, either into memory or a temporary file owned by your own app (depending on the size of photo).

Once the Widget is rendered, you can request the byte array or filename through the `MethodChannel`, and, in Flutter, use the `Image.memory` or `Image.file` constructors to create an Image Widget.

If using the temporary file method, use `getCacheDir()` in Java to find the cache folder. Create your own temporary file name, and copy the file. On the Flutter side, use `package:path_provider - getTemporaryDirectory()` to find the same directory. Just pass the filename across the MethodChannel.

Comment: As the implementation of `path_provider`'s `getTemporaryDirectory()` could conceivably change to use another directory, safer to use the [flutter_android](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_android) plugin's [`Context.cacheDir`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/flutter_android/latest/android_content/Context/cacheDir.html) getter which will exactly match `getCacheDir()` on the Java backend.